# Bing Maps Geocode WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, bing-maps

Currently I'm developing on a BingMapsGeocode Application for WPF (C#).

This little abstract occurs my problems:

```
    <bing:Map Grid.Row="1" CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource MyCredentials}" Center="40,-95"
        core:MapInteractivity.GeocodeResult="{Binding GeocodeResult}"
        ZoomLevel="4" AnimationLevel="Full" >
    </bing:Map>
```

The Error List writes 3 problems down there:

1. The Namespaceprefix "core" is not defined.
2. "MapInteractivity" won't be supported in a WPF-Project
3. "'core' is a not-defined Prefix. Line 20, Position 13."- XML is not valid

If you want to see the whole project you can download and compile on your PC:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3i55h76d0dy80y6/ZycDGnTemV

Thanks for helping,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a `xmlns:core="..."` declaration at the Window or UserControl in your XAML

Comment: I already have this declarations: 
         
         <Window x:Class="BingMapsGeocodeDemo.MainWindow"
                 x:Subclass="MapInteractivity.cs"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:bing="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"


How do you mean should the rest look like?

Comment: sorry you have one for bing, but you don't have one for `xmlns:core="..."`

Comment: sorry for being so annoyingly, but if i include the declaration:         xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
--> nothing happens?

Comment: You're probably not looking for `System.Core`, you should be looking for something bing related. Basically, where is that `core:MapInteractivity` coming from? Probably part of your Bing assemblies. Is there a `Microsoft.Maps.Core` or something similar?